# SQL polygon intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to intersect my position (geography WKT) field with the bounderies of Spain, but I get this exception:

> Implicit conversion of the geography data type to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to execute this query

Even though both data types are geography, what is the problem with this query? Thank You!

(the polygon is bigger, i resume it here to show you)

```
declare @poligonoEspaña geography;
set @poligonoEspaña = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
-17.91124999999994 27.773750000000064,
-17.963889999999935 27.682360000000074,
-17.982779999999934 27.637500000000045,
-18.014449999999954 27.649440000000084,
-18.156109999999956 27.705280000000073,
-18.169859999999915 27.735760000000084,
-18.167499999999905 27.753610000000037,
-18.16110999999995 27.76194000000004))', 4326);

select *
from [PeritosJudiciales].[dbo].[Inmueble]
where Inmueble.Posicion is not null and geography::STGeomFromText(@poligonoEspaña, 4326).STIntersects(Inmueble.Posicion) = 1;
```

I tried using CONVERT for both data types, same result.

Comment: Please add the tag of your used rdbms, e.G. sql server, oracle and so far.

Comment: Addtional, please translate your error message into English or ask your question at https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: translation:

Implicit conversion of the geography data type to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to execute this query.

Comment: SQL SERVER, thank you.

Comment: Сheck if such an error is possible:System.FormatException: 24306: The Polygon input is not valid because the start and end points of the ring number 1 are not the same. Each ring of a polygon must have the same start and end points.

Comment: Inmueble.Posicion is nvarchar, so you should fix that, and yeah, i can't even create your variable locally because it crashes with error

Comment: ValNik, polygon ring has the same start and end points, the problem i guess could be that Spain has different polygons counting its islands.
siggemannen Inmueble.Posicion is a geography field, beware that the polygon i showed is an example cos the real one is huge.

Comment: ``different polygons counting its islands`` - than, you should check intersection with every poligon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for helping me :)

I couldn´t solve it, so i changed the problem approach and it works, I explain:

First I created a table with the fields ID, ID_Anillo (int where I do the separation of each ring of Sapin Limits; it has 14), Latitud and Longitud

Then I set the data of each ring (Is very important that the starting point and the ending points are the same; and the order of the points are correct in order to build the polygons)

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[LimitesEspana]([Latitud], [Longitud], [ID_Anillo])
VALUES (4.273330000000044, 39.96139000000005, 14), etc
```

Then I build 14 polygons.

After that I make the query to check if the properties from table Inmuebles, field Position (geography WKT)  are contained in the polygon. If not, they are deleted.

```
WITH PoligonosEspaña AS (
    SELECT 
        ID_Anillo,
        geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + 
            STUFF((
                SELECT 
                    ', ' + CAST(Longitud AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(Latitud AS VARCHAR(20))
                FROM 
                    [MyBD].[dbo].[LimitesEspana] AS LE_interno
                WHERE 
                    LE_interno.ID_Anillo = LE_externo.ID_Anillo
                ORDER BY 
                    ID  
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') +
        '))', 4326) AS Poligono
    FROM 
        [MyBD].[dbo].[LimitesEspana] AS LE_externo
    GROUP BY 
        ID_Anillo
)
UPDATE I
SET 
    DeletedOn = CASE 
                    WHEN PE.Poligono IS NOT NULL THEN GETDATE()
                    ELSE NULL
               END,
    DeletedBy = CASE 
                    WHEN PE.Poligono IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                    ELSE NULL
               END
FROM 
    [MyBD].[dbo].[Inmueble] AS I
LEFT JOIN 
    PoligonosEspaña AS PE ON I.Posicion.STIntersects(PE.Poligono) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it, it's already a `geography` value.

Just call `STIntersects` directly

```sql
select *
from dbo.Inmueble i
where i.Posicion is not null
  and @poligonoEspaña.STIntersects(i.Posicion) = 1;
```

I think in order to hit indexes it may be better to flip it round

```sql
  and i.Posicion.STIntersects(@poligonoEspaña) = 1;
```